# Camera is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am new to android. In my app, I am accessing camera. But it shows android.hardware.Camera deprecated. I searched for many things; everyone says to use camera2 API. However, where can I implement that Camera2 API. Are there any library files available to fix these issues.

Here is my code:

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you Googled?  Try searching for "android camera2 tutorial" or "android camera2 api".

Comment: "...Use Camera2 API" -- only if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher. Otherwise, you need to use `android.hardware.Camera`, at least for the older devices. "Is there any library file available to fix this issues" -- please explain what "this issues" refers to.

Comment: Android API is the key  my friend.....https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Answer (score 0):

open Android Studio->New ->Import Sample 
then select camera 2 sample app and try to understand it properly